# Filter date w/ timestamp using regex in R

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to use regex to apply a filter to a vector in order to retrieve data that matches the date and timestamp in the following manner: "12/20/2018 6:08 PM"
Example:

```
vec<-c("house", "1 house", house 1", "12/20/2018 6:08 PM", "12/21/2018 11:49 AM", "01/05/2019 11:21 AM")
```

I've tried the following:

```
str_detect(vec, "^[1-9]{2}/[1-9]{2}/[1-9]{2} [1-9]{2}:[1-9]{2} [A,P,M]$")
```

But that doesnt match the timestamp.

Comment: You meant `[0-9]`, not `[1-9]`. Your regex does not match zeros. Also, at the end, there must be `[AP]M`. And more things, like quantifiers... See `^[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4} [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2} [AP]M$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/XVQ378/1))

Comment: Another option that doesn't involve regex would be to convert your vector to datetime first using lubridate and find where it isn't `NA`: `!is.na(lubridate::mdy_hm(vec))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change OP's regex to something like the following:

```
library(stringr)
str_detect(vec, "^[01][0-9]/[0-3][0-9]/[0-9]{4}\\s1?[0-9]:[0-9]{2}\\s[AP]M$")
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Or in Base R:

```
grepl("^[01][0-9]/[0-3][0-9]/[0-9]{4}\\s1?[0-9]:[0-9]{2}\\s[AP]M$", vec)
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

If your goal is to eventually convert the `vec` to a datetime, we can convert directly using `as.POSIXct`:

```
datetime_vec <- as.POSIXct(vec, format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")
# [1] NA                        NA                        NA                       
# [4] "2018-12-20 18:08:00 EST" "2018-12-21 11:49:00 EST" "2019-01-05 11:21:00 EST"
```